# Rails 3: how to write DRYer scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm finding myself writing very similar code in two places, once to define a (virtual) boolean attribute on a model, and once to define a scope to find records that match that condition. In essence,

```
scope :something, where(some_complex_conditions)

def something?
  some_complex_conditions
end
```

A simple example: I'm modelling a club membership; a `Member` pays a `Fee`, which is valid only in a certain `year`.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
  has_many :fees, :through => :payments

  scope :current, joins(:fees).merge(Fee.current)

  def current?
    fees.current.exists?
  end
end

class Fee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
  has_many :members, :through => :payments

  scope :current, where(:year => Time.now.year)

  def current?
    year == Time.now.year
  end
end
```

Is there a DRYer way to write a scopes that make use of virtual attributes (or, alternatively, to determine whether a model is matched by the conditions of a scope)?

I'm pretty new to Rails so please do point out if I'm doing something stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no better way to do what you're trying to do (other than to take note of Geraud's comment).  In your scope you're defining a class-level filter which will generate SQL to be used in restricting the results your finders return, in the attribute you're defining an instance-level test to be run on a specific instance of this class.

Yes, the code is similar, but it's performing different functions in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

This in not an answer to the question, but your code has a bug (in case you use something similar in production): Time.now.year will return the year the server was started. You want to run this scope in a lambda to have it behave as expected.

```
scope :current, lambda { where(:year => Time.now.year) }
```

Comment: In OP's example, wouldn't the time be calculated when the code is first executed rather than at server start? Or is that synonymous with server start.

Comment: Thanks, good catch. @Dobry: I think you're right, Rails will load the model as needed so it won't exactly be at server start... but either way it's not the intended effect!

Comment: @dobry: you are totally right. It is what I meant and I should have been more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use one or more parameters with a lambda in your scopes. Suppose that you have a set of items, and you want to get back those that are either 'Boot' or 'Helmet' :

```
  scope :item_type, lambda { |item_type|
    where("game_items.item_type = ?", item_type )
  }
```

You can now do game_item.item_type('Boot') to get only the boots or game_item.item_type('Helmet') to get only the helmets. The same applies in your case. You can just have a parameter in your scope, in order to check one or more conditions on the same scope, in a DRYer way.

Comment: Thanks, but although this would let me write multiple related scopes in a DRY way, I'm not sure that this helps me write a method like `boot?` without having to repeat the `item_type == 'Boot'` logic.

Comment: you can do that as well. Just create a method or scope like is(type) and use it like is('Boot'). Then, your finder selects items based on the string you directly provide, so that you do not have to check on the item_type=='Boot' everytime.

Comment: def boot?; GameItem.item_type('Boot').where(:id => self.id).exists?; end